# updating value of object inside of array based on id of different object in different array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

if I have an array like this:

```
const[arr,setArr] = React.useState([
{label:"dummy01",id:2},
{label:"dummy02",id:5},

])
```

is there anyway to update `arr` with such array:

```
const newArray = [{label:'dummy Altered01',id:2},{label:'different',id:10},{label:'different 02',id:55}}
```

what I expect to have an array like this :

```
[
{label:"dummy Altered01",id:2},
{label:"dummy02",id:5},
{label:'different',id:10},
{label:'different 02',id:55}
]
```

as you can see the object with the id of `2` is updated and other new objects are added to the array without erasing previous `dummy02`.

I don't know how should I compare `id` inside of two different arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not the best answer, so here's what I got

```
let listOfIds = newArray.map(item => item.id)
newArray = newArray.concat(arr.filter(item => !listOfIds.includes(item.id)))
```

First you map the `newArray` into a list of IDs.
Then `newArray` concatenates with the filtered original array (i.e. the array now doesn't have any items with ids in common with the latter )

Finally you update the state by `setArr(newArr)`

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider

```
a = [{label:"dummy01",id:2},{label:"dummy02",id:5}]
```

and new array is

```
b= [{label:'dummy Altered01',id:2},{label:'different',id:10},{label:'different 02',id:55}]
```

Now perform itearation over new array

```
b.forEach((item)=>{
    let index = a.findIndex((x)=>x.id == item.id) 
    if(index > -1){
       a[index].label = item.label
    }
    else
    a.push(item)
})

console.log(a)
```

Comment: how can I implement this in react

Comment: @DennisQuan it will erase previous values. if I try to spread, it will add new one instead of updating